# How do I set in Laravel Pagination Custom Query String?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a link like this:
`https:localhost/&sort=latest?page=1`
And I want to make it custom like so:
`https:localhost/?page=1&sort=latest`

Can I choose to put it first or is just always last ?

Comment: it was just an example i am talking about the get paramter for pagination if i can put it first why is so hard to understand

Comment: You could, but it would mean making a custom `Paginator` class that extends `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator`, then reimplementing the `url` function that comes from `Illuminat\Pagination\AbstractPaginator`, then binding it to the container. It's not worth it in my opinion.

Comment: The default logic adds every query parameter that doesn't come from the paginator first, and then appends the `page` value.